# Cursor is not visible in EditText after setting visibility VISIBLE

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginSmall"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/searchCloseIcon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchIcon"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_white"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint=" Search Nearby Chat"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black38"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sunheading" />
```

Initially I can see cursor in edittext but after setting its visibility gone 
and 
**again making visible its not visible in edittext**.

May I know what can be the solution for this?

Comment: check color Accent in your theme you may have same color in it as your background color. that's why your cursor is not visible

Answer (score 6):

to show cursor,

```
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and In your `EditText`, use the property: to make it drawable

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/blue_cursor"
```

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color

**programatically** :

```
searchTextView.setCursorVisible(true);
searchTextView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: than you might need to do it programatecally

Answer (score 0):

When you set your container visibility VISIBLE also try to request focus to your EditText

```
findViewById(R.id.searchTextView).requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"